# Как сделать кастомный календарь в Android?

Tags: android, календарь

Хочу добавить в приложение подобный календарь:

**Удалено намеренно, не возвращайте изображение**

Сам написать врядли смогу, 2 месяца в Android. Пытаюсь подключить существующие решения, но сталкиваюсь с трудностями из - за отсутствия в них нужного функционала.

Может кто подскажет что правильнее было бы использовать в моём случае? Или может я чего пропустил в существующих решениях?

Необходимо две вещи:
- Иметь возможность пометить любой день одним или несколькими круглыми маркерами(достаточно иметь возможности прикрепить несколько drawable/xml/...).
- Иметь возможность поставить background у любого дня(хоть как - нибудь, даже Color будет достаточно)

Что я пробовал и почему решения не прижились:

- https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View - нельзя добавлять несколько маркеров. Есть решение через xml,позволяющее прикрепить ко дню одну xml из заранее определенного количества маркеров определенного цвета, но так как разных маркеров суммарно ~ 10, потребуется гигантское количество xml.
- https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid - нет возможности отметить несколько маркеров.
- https://github.com/ApplikeySolutions/CosmoCalendar - нет возможности отметить несколько маркеров.
- https://github.com/snollidea/peppy-calendarview - выглядит здорово, но не ставится: `ERROR: Failed to resolve:`
- https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView - Нет возможности поставить backgroung для дня
- https://github.com/huanghaibin-dev/CalendarView - Очень жаль, но падает из - за атрибута `app:week_bar_view="com.haibin.calendarviewproject.EnglishWeekBar"`
- Пробовал отредачить либу https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView, убился об её сложность.
- https://github.com/square/android-times-square - нет возможности использовать маркеры

Comment: так либ много, ваши замечания по ним оч легко доделать. Форкните более подходящую https://github.com/snollidea/peppy-calendarview вот эта почти 1 в 1 что вам нужно, даже по нужде заказчика пилите фичи. на ваш вопрос ответ - написать. Так как он очень большой без конкретных проблем и поэтому решить его можно многими путями в итоге он звучит: "сделайте мне"

Comment: Я как раз ковыряюсь в этой либе в попытках что - то похожее на свой календарь сделать(пока борюсь с тьмой ошибок). Задавая вопрос я думал о том, что кто - нибудь с SO уже делал что - то подобное и поделится решением, либо укажет на либу, которую я пропустил. Т.к в разработке я совсем уж недавно, то я не ожидал что мне придётся в чью - то чужую либу лезть.=)

Comment: Зачем удалять картинку, показывающую что именно ты хочешь получить?

Comment: Потому что это уже реализовано и я не хочу "светить" то что задействовано в существующем работающем проекте. Я хотел бы вообще удалить вопрос, т.к действительно полезных и заплюсованных ответов здесь не представлено, но у меня это не получается(логика SO не даёт возможности, тревоги - отклоняются). Так что я просто удалю картинку. Не восстанавливайте её. Или просто убейте вопрос, если можете. Если снимется репутация за голоса - пускай.

Comment: SO не фриланс-биржа, где публикуют заказы и удаляют их после выполнения. SO это по большей части Википедия проблем и решений. Опубликованный вопрос вам *не принадлежит*. Поставил тревогу на вопрос, пусть модераторы посмотрят и примут решение как быть.

Comment: Давайте примем компромисное решение? Сам вопрос интересен даже без картинки и кто-то когда-то, возможно, напишет ответ с описанием базовой логики создания подобного виджета. Также в вопросе есть ссылки на разные либы - это тоже может быть кому-то полезно. Таким образом, думаю, вопрос стоит оставить, пусть даже и без картинки, хотя и не очень мне понятно чем она мешает)

Comment: Ок, давайте оставим. Я бы не хотел продолжать полемику в отношении картинки, предлагаю подвести черту такой формулировкой: я не хочу, чтобы действующий проект как - то ассоциировался с этим вопросом на SO.

Answer (score 0):

[Переделывал чьё-то на GitHub](https://github.com/kofnal/CalendarProject).
Оригинал был с ошибочной генерацией дат.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -2):

Как вариант, могу вам предложить взглянуть на очень интересное решение: 
https://github.com/square/android-times-square

Использование календаря довольно простое, плюс нужный вам функционал, как подсвечивание определенных дат или выделение текущей, уже присутствует. Поэтому, нужно всего лишь отредактировать бакграунд и сделать его в виде круга.

Comment: Вариант действительно хороший. В теории я смог бы отредачить границы ячеек, только вот выделение нужных дат точками я сделать не смогу: календарь предоставляет свой `cellView` в которым нет вообще никаких методов для кастомизации, поэтому придётся пользоваться дефолтными `setBackgroundColor` и.т.д, которые к результату не приведут.

Answer (score -2):

Слишком у вас уверенные замечания для человека который два месяца в разработке, похоже у Вас есть неплохой опыт в разработке в других направлениях. А соответственно могу вам посоветовать глубже изучить `ConstraintLayout` или на крайняк `RelativeLayout`, хотя в теперешних трендах первое предпочтительнее и вы (в общем количестве с изучением и разработкой) затратите максимум неделю на решение этой задачи, но вы за то будете понимать как варится эта вся тема и без особых усилий сможете модифицировать любую библиотеку (хотя это скорее всего вам не понадобится), вы увидите что реально это всё намного проще чем кажется.

А использовать чужие библиотеки это хорошо, но только если они полностью или почти полностью покрывают вашу задачу, не только визуально но и логикой работы.

P.S. Ведь в итоге вы потратите тоже самое время и плюс придёте к этому же.